# Spark configuration, what is the difference of SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY, SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY, and SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY?

Tags: linux, memory, apache-spark, environment-variables, config

I did my work, read the documentation at https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html

> in spark-folder/conf/spark-env.sh:

- **SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY**, Memory for Master (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 512 Mb)
- **SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY**, Memory per Worker (e.g. 1000M, 2G) (Default: 1G)
- **SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY**, to set how much total memory workers have to give executors (e.g. 1000m, 2g)

what is the relationship of above 3 parameters?

As I understand, DRIVER_MEMORY is the max memory master node/process can request. But for driver, how about multiple machine situation, eg. 1 master machine and 2 worker machine, worker machine should also have some memory available for spark driver?

EXECUTOR_MEMORY and WORKER_MEMORY are the same to me, just different names, could this also be explained please?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First, you should know that 1 **Worker** (you can say 1 machine or 1 Worker Node) can launch multiple **Executors** (or multiple **Worker Instances** - the term they use in the docs).

- `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY` is only used in **standalone** deploy mode
- `SPARK_EXECUTOR_MEMORY` is used in **YARN** deploy mode

In Standalone mode, you set `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY` to the total amount of memory can be used on **one machine** (All Executors on this machine) to run your spark applications.

In contrast, In YARN mode, you set `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY` to the memory of **one Executor**

- `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY` is used in YARN deploy mode, specifying the memory for the Driver that runs your application & communicates with Cluster Manager.

Comment: I used to confuse about these terms when I started learning Spark as you.
You can refer to my blog for more understandings. Hopefully it would helps :)
http://www.trongkhoanguyen.com/2015/01/understand-spark-deployment-modes.html#more