# SparkR-submit core not allocated

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, sparkr

Hi I'm working on SparkR on yarn mode.

When I submit an application in this way:

```
./spark-submit --master yarn-client --packages com.databricks:spark-
csv_2.10:1.0.3 --driver-memory 6g --num-executors 8 --executor-memory 6g 
--total-executor-cores 32 --executor-cores 8 /home/sentiment/Scrivania/test3.R
```

One node start as AM (I think is chosen randomly) and take 1gb of Memory and 1 Vcore.
After that ALL nodes has 7Gb of Memory and 1 Vcore for each one. (Except for the node who starts AM that has 8gb and 2core)

**Why nodes do not acquire 4 cores as configuration/spark submit says?**

**spark-default**

```
spark.master    spark://server1:7077
spark.serializer        org.apache.spark.serializer.KryoSerializer
spark.driver.memory 5g
spark.executor.memory   6g
spark.executor.cores    4
spark.akka.frameSize    1000
spark.yarn.am.cores 4
spark.kryoserializer.buffer.max 700m
spark.kryoserializer.buffer 100m
```

**Yarn-manager**

```
<configuration>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services</name>
      <value>mapreduce_shuffle</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.nodemanager.aux-services.mapreduce.shuffle.class</name>
      <value>org.apache.hadoop.mapred.ShuffleHandler</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.resource-tracker.address</name>
      <value>server1:8025</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.scheduler.address</name>
      <value>server1:8035</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.address</name>
      <value>server1:8050</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.resourcemanager.webapp.address</name>
      <value>server1:8088</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>yarn.scheduler.minimum-allocation-vcores</name>
      <value>4</value>
   </property>
</configuration>
```

*Update1:*

Read from old post that I needed to change the value of this property below from Default to Dominant at `capacity-scheduler.xml`

```
<property>
   <name>yarn.scheduler.capacity.resource-calculator</name>
<value>org.apache.hadoop.yarn.util.resource.DominantResourceCalculator</value>
</property>
```

Added at Spark-env

```
SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=4
```

Nothing changed.

*Update2:* 
I read this from spark official page, **so 1 core for each executor in Yarn mode is the maximum value?**

> spark.executor.cores  The number of cores to use on each executor. For
>   YARN and standalone mode only. In standalone mode, setting this
>   parameter allows an application to run multiple executors on the same
>   worker, provided that there are enough cores on that worker.
>   Otherwise, only one executor per application will run on each worker.

Comment: can you change setenv.sh?  Have a look at : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34762432/spark-ignores-spark-worker-memory/

Comment: I added at `spark-env`
SPARK_EXECUTOR_CORES=4  but nothing changed